# Unable to Install Psutil Linux Bash

Tags: python, linux, bash

I have been trying to install Psutil but consistently facing the following error. I saw that there exist many solutions to this problem using sudo install python3-devel but my server only runs bash commands.

Is there a Bash specific solution / command I could use?

```
Failed to build psutil
Installing collected packages: psutil
    Running setup.py install for psutil ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /opt/python/3.7.5/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-pnv8vynd/psutil/setup.p
y'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-pnv8vynd/psutil/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'
"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-4zlijwis/install-record.txt -
-single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-pnv8vynd/psutil/
    Complete output (41 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil
    copying psutil/_psbsd.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil
    copying psutil/_psposix.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil
    copying psutil/_pswindows.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil
    copying psutil/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil
    copying psutil/_pslinux.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil
    copying psutil/_psaix.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil
    copying psutil/_pssunos.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil
    copying psutil/_common.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil
    copying psutil/_compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil
    copying psutil/tests/test_linux.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_windows.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_process.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_misc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_memory_leaks.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_system.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_osx.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_posix.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_sunos.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_aix.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_bsd.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/runner.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_unicode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests
    running build_ext
    building 'psutil._psutil_linux' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=567 -DPSUTIL_LINUX=1 -DPS
UTIL_ETHTOOL_MISSING_TYPES=1 -I/opt/python/3.7.5/include/python3.7m -c psutil/_psutil_common.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_commo
n.o
    unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /opt/python/3.7.5/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pi
p-install-pnv8vynd/psutil/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-pnv8vynd/psutil/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__
file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-rec
ord-4zlijwis/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: You seem to miss the GNU C Compiler (`gcc`). What output do you get when you type `which gcc`?

Comment: I get no output when I try that

Comment: Then you either don't have `gcc` installed or it's not on the `PATH`. Easiest might be to try and install it: `sudo apt install gcc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you can run this:

```
#!/bin/bash/
apt-get update  # To get the latest package lists
sudo apt-get install gcc python3-dev
apt-get install psutil -y
```

Comment: apt install gcc was enough for me to get it to work!

Comment: python3-dev was the problem in kali Linux